# Can you put static folder in project root, rather than app root?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

For example, if I want to use the same style.css for all my apps, where should I put the static folder? I'm pretty sure Django site says to put it in the application folder? But what if I have multiple apps?

Answer (score 1):

Django doesn't say any such thing. Put the static folder wherever you want, as long as you include it in STATICFILES_DIRS so that collectstatic will find it.

Answer (score 1):

You can create separate `static` folder for all apps and set [`STATICFILES_DIRS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#std:setting-STATICFILES_DIRS) accordingly.

I personally use the following project layout

```
project/apps/app_1
             ...
             app_n
             static        <- static files for all apps
             templates     <- templates for all apps

       /config/...
               settings.py
               ...
```

which I borrowed from [Two Scoops of Django book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0981467342)